# Assign order based on most rows are not null in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, window-functions

I am generating all combinations for variables and insert into temp table

```
select *
from (select 33 as age union all select null) a cross join
     (select 44 as totaldd union all select null) t cross join
     (select 30 as timeperiod union all select null) d cross join
     (select CURDATE() as StartDateTime union all select null) s
```

Results are:

[image]

I want order based on most rows are not null Like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with `dense_rank()` and conditional expressions:

```
select 
    a.age, 
    t.totaldd, 
    d.timeperiod, 
    s.startdatetime,
    dense_rank() over(order by 
          (a.age is null) 
        + (t.totaldd is null) 
        + (d.timeperiod is null) 
        + (s.startdatetime is null)
    ) as rn
from (select 33 as age union all select null) a cross join
     (select 44 as totaldd union all select null) t cross join
     (select 30 as timeperiod union all select null) d cross join
     (select CURDATE() as startdatetime union all select null) s
```

Actually you can even do this without the window function, with just the conditional expressions:

```
select 
    a.age, 
    t.totaldd, 
    d.timeperiod, 
    s.startdatetime,
    1 + (a.age is null) 
        + (t.totaldd is null) 
        + (d.timeperiod is null) 
        + (s.startdatetime is null) as rn
from (select 33 as age union all select null) a cross join
     (select 44 as totaldd union all select null) t cross join
     (select 30 as timeperiod union all select null) d cross join
     (select CURDATE() as startdatetime union all select null) s
```